# Multiple Users Login Swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

I'm creating an application where multiple users can login.
After successful login user will be navigated to next View controller.(Like student will be navigated to student dashboard, teacher will be navigated to teacher dashboard etc)

Currently i stored some users in array, but i don't know how to navigate the users to the respective dashboard.

**This is my code :**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var txtUserName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var worgLogin: UILabel!

let user1 = ["user": "Karsten","userID":"1","userName":"Kalle","passWord":"1234" ]
let user2 = ["user": "Rene","userID":"2","userName":"Rene" ,"passWord":"1234" ]
let user3 = ["user": "Johan","userID":"3","userName":"Johan","passWord":"1234" ]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let array = [user1,user2,user3]
    UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: "users")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ISUSERLOGGEDIN") == true {
        //user is already logged in just navigate him to home screen
        let homeVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeVc, animated: false)
    }
}

@IBAction func authenticateUser(_ sender: Any) {
    if txtUserName.text == "userName" && txtPassword.text == "passWord" {    
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ISUSERLOGGEDIN")
        let homeVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeVc, animated: true)
    }else {
        displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "Brugernavn eller Password er skrevet forkert");            
        return;
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:String)
{        
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message:userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert);        
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style:UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:nil);        
    myAlert.addAction(okAction);        
    self.present(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);        
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add 1 more parameter in array of "Type" and provide the different values.
When you are authenticating user, check the type and navigate the user to their respective dashboard.

**Example:**

- If type is student, navigate the user to student dashboard.
- If type is teacher, navigate the user to teacher dashboard.